# rails 4 accepts_nested_attributes_for on Multiple Table Inheritance Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails 4 project, and I'm using MTI. It's a forum app, and I have a core Topic model in addition to several models that inherit from Topic, like Announcement and Private Message.

Here's how it all works:

models/topic.rb - this is the base model

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable

  default_scope order('created_at DESC')

  #string title

  belongs_to :discussable, polymorphic: true, dependent: :destroy

  belongs_to :author, class_name: User
  has_many :posts, inverse_of: :topic, order: :created_at
  has_many :viewings
  has_many :viewers, class_name: User, through: :viewings, uniq: true
  has_many :watchings
  has_many :watchers, class_name: User, through: :watchings, uniq: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts, allow_destroy: true

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :author_id, presence: true

  def base
    self
  end

end
```

models/announcement.rb

```
# this is a "child" class -- acts_as_topic sets that up, see next snippet
class Announcement < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_topic

  default_scope includes(:topic).order('topics.created_at DESC')

  #datetime :displays_at
  validates :expires_at, timeliness: { after: lambda { self.displays_at }, allow_nil: true }

end
```

config/initializers/discussable.rb

```
module Discussable
  def self.included(base)
    base.has_one :topic, as: :discussable, autosave: true
    base.validate :topic_must_be_valid
    base.alias_method_chain :topic, :autobuild
  end

  def topic_with_autobuild
    topic_without_autobuild || build_topic
  end

  def method_missing(meth, *args, &blk)
    topic.send(meth, *args, &blk)
  rescue NoMethodError
    super
  end

  protected
  def topic_must_be_valid
    unless topic.valid?
      topic.errors.each do |attr, message|
        errors.add(attr, message)
      end
    end
  end
end

class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.acts_as_topic
    include Discussable
  end
end
```

And the migrations:

```
class CreateTopics < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :topics do |t|
      t.string :title, null: false
      t.references :author, null: false

      t.references :discussable
      t.string :discussable_type

      t.integer :posts_count, null: false, default: 0

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateAnnouncements < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :announcements do |t|
      t.datetime :displays_at
      t.datetime :expires_at
    end
  end
end
```

views/announcements/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @announcement do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: 'Title' %><br />
    <%= f.fields_for :posts do |post_f| %>
        <%= post_f.text_area :content %>
        <%= post_f.hidden_field :author_id, value: current_user.id %><br />
    <% end %>
    <%= f.text_field :tag_list, placeholder: 'Tags' %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :displays_at, placeholder: 'Display At' %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :expires_at, placeholder: 'Expire At' %><br />
    <%= f.hidden_field :author_id %><br />
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The announcements#create action is trivial -- it just makes a new Announcement from the params, and tries to save it.

There are no errors with this setup, everything appears to work perfectly.

The problem is that announcements#create creates the announcement and totally ignores the nested attributes for the post.

It makes sense because `acts_as_topic` really just creates a has_one relationship between the Announcement model and the Topic model, and the Discussable module fakes it like the announcement is_a Topic even though it's really not.

So my question is: how can I fake it such that the internals of the ActiveRecord initializer for the Announcement model accepts the nested attributes for posts, which is actually an association with the Topic model?